# Image overlay fails using FFMPEG4Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to watermark a video using FFMPEG4Android.
I am using the app on the android market from [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss_dev2.ffmpeg_android2&hl=en).

The command used is

> ffmpeg -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -i /sdcard/videokit/logos/1.png -i
>   /sdcard/videokit/logos/2.png -i /logos/3.png -filter_complex
>   "[0:v][1:v]
>   overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,0,1)'
>   [tmp]; [tmp][2:v]
>   overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,2,3)'
>   [tmp2]; [tmp2][3:v]
>   overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,4,5)'"
>   /sdcard/videokit/output.mp4

But everytime I run the command the app fails

> Opening an output file:
>   overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='between(t,0,1)'.
>   No such filter: '' Error configuring filters. exit_program: 1

Can I get any help for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use complex command, check the [ffmpeg4android](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) blog for examples